How do I resolve conflicts with SwiftData?
SwiftData includes support for CloudKit sync. However, I don't see any way to add conflict resolution behavior. For example, if different devices set different values for a field, or if a relationship is orphaned because of a deletion on another device, the application has to handle this somehow.
In Core Data (which SwiftData wraps), you can handle this with the conflict resolution system (docs) and classes like NSMergePolicy.
Is any of this accessible in SwiftData? If not, how do you deal with conflicts when syncing a SwiftData model with the cloud?

It doesn't seem that you do - the last save just overwrites everything without even throwing an error.
Here's a bit of experiment to see it in detail:
1.. Insert the original object through the main context:
let ctx1 = container.mainContext
let insertedObject = Icon(tag: 1)
ctx1.insert(insertedObject)
print("## insertedObject:", insertedObject.tag) // 1
try ctx1.save()

2.. Change the tag through another context:
let ctx2 = ModelContext(container)
let obj2: Icon = try ctx2.existingModel(for: insertedObject.persistentModelID)!
obj2.tag = 2
try ctx2.save()

3.. Fetching from yet another context provides the latest change:
let ctx3 = ModelContext(container)
let obj3: Icon = try ctx3.existingModel(for: insertedObject.persistentModelID)!
print("## obj3:", obj3.tag) // 2

4.. Refectching from the original context does not pick up the change:
let objRefetchedFromMain: Icon = try ctx1.fetchedModel(for: insertedObject.persistentModelID)!
print("## objRefetchedFromMain: ", objRefetchedFromMain.tag) // 1

5.. Repeated save does nothing as the context thinks it has nothing new to save (somewhat expectedly):
try ctx1.save()
let ctx4 = ModelContext(container)
let obj4: Icon = try ctx4.existingModel(for: insertedObject.persistentModelID)!
print("## obj4:", obj4.tag) // 2

6.. However, if there IS a change to the original, it just writes it on top of any other:
insertedObject.tag = 3
try ctx1.save() // no errors here!
let ctx5 = ModelContext(container)
let obj5: Icon = try ctx5.existingModel(for: insertedObject.persistentModelID)!
print("## obj5:", obj5.tag) // 3

This is freakin outrageous - esp. taking into account that the whole thing is built upon core data and they already have all the tools to make it work properly.
And what's the point of having multiple contexts if they can't be synced in any reasonable way?
p.s.: existingModel has been taken from here; fetchedModel is the second part of the method (starting from "let fetchDescriptor...")
